Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.fxml not found
I am trying to build JavaFX application in the Apache NetBeans IDE 21 and keep facing this error whenever I try to run the program. I have created a library linked to the JavaFX SDK and also added the --module-path "D:\javafx-sdk-22.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml to the VM options as well.
I've tried methods like clean and building first and some other solutions on the internet.

A project using [tag:maven], for example, is more flexible, but the approach shown here has its uses.

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/
